# Loop through categories and get bottom-most category for each tree

Tags: templating, categories

[image]

I need to get the last item that don't have a child. So in this case I need

Mobiltelefoner
Ipad
Køleskab
Vaskemaskine

How to I get the last item that don't have a child without knowing the amount of levels?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Craft’s [`nav`](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/nav) tag, which allows to recursively iterate through
an array of element models. Only output the category title if the category has no descendants.

```
{% nav category in categories %}
    {% if not category.getDescendants().total() %}
        <span>{{ category.title }}</span>
    {% endif %}

    {% ifchildren %}
        {% children %}
    {% endifchildren %}
{% endnav %}
```

Another option would be to write a self-calling [`macro`](https://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/1.x/tags/macro.html) to recursively traverse the tree.

```
{% macro getBottomMostElements(elements) %}
    {% import _self as self %}

    {% for element in elements %}
        {% if element.getDescendants().total() %}
            {{ self.getBottomMostElements(element.getDescendants(1)) }}
        {% else %}
            <span>{{ element.title }}</span>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endmacro %}

{% import _self as macros %}
{{ macros.getBottomMostElements(categories.level(1)) }}
```

Comment: I've tried the code above, but it doesn't give the result that I want. Even though the entry category has 4 items when I add it to the loop it loops through all the 7 original categories. 

I'm still getting a flat array....

Comment: You shouldn't add it to your loop but replace your loop with it. `categories` has to be an ElementCriteriaModel.

Comment: Still no luck @Beuschau?

Comment: No still no luck. 
Please take a look at this image [http://imgur.com/a/tdghB](http://imgur.com/a/tdghB)

Comment: I tested both of these snippets and they do exactly what you want, output categories that have no children. I am pretty sure you’re passing in the wrong data for `categories`, which has to be an ElementCriteriaModel prepared to query for categories. Try the snippet with `{% set categories = craft.categories %}` set and it will work. I see in your picture that you have the field in a Matrix block, so the `categories` var would need to be set with something like `{% set categories = block.myCategoriesFieldHandle %}`.

Comment: I am using block.categories in var